# How to avoid signing with expired certificates?

Tags: install4j

Last week we found out that our maven build process runs successfully including the signing process by install4j either the certificates were expired. Other project using the windows sign tool directly runs also into this problem but were informed by the broken maven build. So is there a flag or something at install4j to activate any validation of the expiredate of the certificates so the build will be broken when they are invalid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 6.1.4 there is no such flag, I have added this to our issue tracker.